# Random codes appearing at the end of URLs (WordPress site)

Tags: wordpress

I use WordPress on my website and I've noticed the following code at the end of URLs when viewing pages/posts. The codes vary depending on the browser (Chrome, Safari and Firefox.)

- Chrome: `#.T08yOCM5CDU`
- Safari: `#.T08yRZg5D8s`
- Firefox: `#.T08yaiM5CDU`

Is it simply a way for Google to track my site's hits?

Are my readers seeing this?

My site's URL is http://www.internationalpolicydigest.org/

Edited to reflect the plugins that my website is using:

- AddThis Social Bookmarking Widget
- Adminer
- Disqus Comment System
- Donate Plus
- Facebook Revised Open Graph Meta Tag
- Front Page Category
- Google XML Sitemaps
- HTML in Author Bio
- Image Widget
- Just Another Author Widget
- No category parents
- Outbrain
- Page Links To
- Quick Page/Post Redirect DEV
- Relevanssi
- Search & Replace
- Widget Context
- Woo Recent Posts
- WP-PageNavi
- WP Easy Gallery

Comment: Can you update your question with what wordpress plugins you are using. I'm pretty sure one of them is causing this.

Comment: I made the requested edit.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this on a site I worked on - The client had enabled **'Track address bar shares'** in the **addthis plugin**. Un-ticking this option removed the codes from the sites URLs

Comment: Outbrain made it a huge hassle but eventually worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... It's not listed, but your Outbrain rater script is causing this.

in your page source:
`http://widgets.outbrain.com/OutbrainRater.js`

I found this by looking at that file's source and here's the culprit:

```
(var e="",f=0;f<8;f++){var g=Math.floor(Math.random()*61);e+="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(g,g+1)
```

In your index.php or header.php file you should see the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <!--
    //OBSTART:do_NOT_remove_this_comment
    var OutbrainPermaLink="http://www.internationalpolicydigest.org/2012/02/29/africa-nuclear-security-and-the-2012-summit/";
    if(typeof(OB_Script)!='undefined'){OutbrainStart();} else {
    var OB_PlugInVer="7.0.0.0_Regular";;var OB_raterMode="stars";var OB_recMode="rec";var OBITm="1297817213";var OB_Script=true;var OB_langJS="http://widgets.outbrain.com/lang_en.js";document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://widgets.outbrain.com/OutbrainRater.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));}
    //OBEND:do_NOT_remove_this_comment
    //-->
    </script>
```

- Copy/Paste it into Notepad (so you can save it if you really want it)
- delete it from the file you edited.
- Clear any cache you have (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>)
- Clear your domain cookies (just to be safe)
- load your site.

This should take care of your issue.

It also looks like you have an outbrain plugin on your site: `no category parents, outbrain` this may be the source of this as well.

Comment: That's great thank you.  Hopefully by following those steps that should take care of it.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: While I'm extremely comfortable with WordPress because getting one line of code can damage a site I am paying someone to fix it.  Hopefully it does.  My thinking is that the code, while probably not the end of the world, does more or less hurt my site's visibility in Google and elsewhere.  I recently rebranded my site with a new URL so I had to start from scratch from site visits in the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: I'll keep you posted though.

Comment: Good luck! I'm hopeful my suggestion works for you. Random question: Was this affecting your analytics as well since the analytics javascript was firing after this bit of javascript did?

Comment: I suspect it did affect my overall site visits.  I'm steadfast of the quality of my site so my theory is that something had to be affecting how my site was getting viewed and how it appeared in Google, Bing and Yahoo.

Comment: Just an update to the Outbrain issue it was in-fact caused by a tracking code that can be deactivated in case someone else has the problem.